# JSON differences with javascript and googlescript

Tags: javascript, php, json, email, google-app-engine

I am using google script to log form data from a webpage and then email it to another email address without the user having to use their email client.  It's all working and now I'm trying to format the JSON output in the body of the email and even following guides and other questions on here, the body will not format. I would like to break up the information by creating a new line which I thought would be as simple as adding "\n" but that did not work for me in the google environment. here is the code I am using

```
Logger.log(e);
MailApp.sendEmail(TO_ADDRESS, "Quote Form Submitted", JSON.strinify(e.parameters));
```

Also in case it would help this is what the emails currently look like, the form is made up of 2 sections of checkboxes and the rest are either single line text input or text area input

```
{"CompanyName":["Test  Company"],"Garage":["on"],"Customer":["on"],"Start":["2016-12-21"],"SpecialService":["None"],"ProvingGround":["on"],"ContactInfo":["1234  Candy Cane Ln. "],"End":["2016-12-29"],"ContactName":["John  Doe"],"ContactTitle":["IT Support"],"Other":["on"]}
```

Is there a way to do this, or would I be better off attacking this in a different way?

Comment: Seems really odd to be emailing JSON values rather than moving data directly between endpoints.

Comment: I'm very new to this kind of stuff so it very well may be an odd way to go about doing it, but its one that I found that looked simple enough.  How would you recommend going about something like this? I got it to print like how I wanted but if there is a better way I'd be open to trying it

Comment: It probably depends on what you're trying to do. What ulltimately happens with the JSON data?

Answer (score 2):

[`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has built-in options to pretty print the output. You can hand it a replacer function for changing outputted values and a number indicated the indentation level.

```js
var data = {
  a: {
    b: 'c',
    d: 'e',
  },
  f: {
    g: {
      h: {
        i: 'j'
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log('Normal:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log('Pretty-printed:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```